# How to Read Register Map From COM serial port using Modbus Protocol? (c++)

Tags: c++, serial-port, modbus

I have a hardware device that connects to the computer's COM port using a usb to RS232 connector. It uses the Modbus RTU protocol. I'm trying to read the registers using C++ on Visual Studio, do I need an external library for this (if so where could I find one)? Or are there default libraries in C++ that can do this?

I've googled Modbus libraries for C++ but only found results for specific hardware like Arduino.

Comment: *"I'm trying to read the registers..."* -- You neglect to mention what kind of OS is running on your *"computer"*.  The OS will probably  prevent you from accessing those registers because it already has a device driver to handle the I/O.  Your userspace program should use system calls to read and write data instead of trying to directly access peripheral registers.

Comment: I'm using windows 10 OS

Comment: Windows 10 will prevent application programs from trying to directly access any device registers.  You have to use system calls, and transfer data through buffers.

Answer (score 1):

To write your own software that communicates with Modbus devices you need a library.

[Libmodbus](https://github.com/stephane/libmodbus) works very well. It's written in C but you can use it in C++. There is a Visual Studio project file included in the repo.

Otherwise, if you are familiar with Qt, you can take a look at this [master example](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtserialbus-modbus-master-example.html).

In case you don't want to start from scratch you can take a look at [QModMaster](https://sourceforge.net/projects/qmodmaster/), which uses libmodbus and Qt. If you want to start testing your device right away before you get busy coding you can download the binary files for Windows or compile the project with Qt Studio if you're on Linux.